# ta.valuewhen() shows me only the result computed on the last bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

With Pine Script, I am trying to create a script to plot the number of bars I need to go back to find a bar that has a lower close value. As I need this function to be computed on every bar, if my time series is:
`(bar_index,(open,close)): [(0,(1,2)),(1,(2,4)),(2,(4,8)),(3,(8,8)),(4,(8,5)),(5,(5,3)),(6,(3,1)),(7,(1,5)),(8,(5,9)),(9,(9,8))]`
I am trying to build a script that returns (and plots)
`(bar_index,result): [(0,na),(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,5),(6,na),(7,1),(8,1),(9,2)]`

I tried this:

```
lower_close(src) => ta.valuewhen(close<src, bar_index, 1)
var a = close
plot(lower_close(a))
```

but it returns:
`(bar_index,result): [(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1),(6,1),(7,1),(8,1),(9,1)]`

I got the feeling that it returns the result of the last bar it was computed on (bar_index=8 for the example above, as the value of the 9th bar will be executed only when the bar will close) for every bar.

Does anyone have a clue how I can solve my problem?

Comment: in your example code there is an error `close < close`

Comment: @Gu5tavo71, I am pretty sure that `var a = close` makes the two `close` different